# Javascript Bootstrap Table Cell and Column Values

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

Having trouble accessing my table values. How can I access the header value of the value i click on. Also how can i access the first index based on the cell i click on? For example click on the name but get the Uid of that persons name.

[image]

Right now this is retrieving the value of the cell but i need more functionality.

```
<script>

    $("#table").on("click", "td", function (row, $el, field) {

        var col = $(this)[0].textContent

        alert(col);

    });

</script>
```

Comment: try using $el instead of $(this)

Answer (score 0):

You need to go traverse upwards from the td to its ancestor tr using .closest() and then into the first td of that row using .find() and then use.text() to get the text content of that cell.

This could all be done in one hit by chaining the jquery methods together, but I have separated it below to show the steps.

```js
    $("#table").on("click", "td", function () {
        var parentTr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var firstCellContent  = parentTr.find('td:eq(0)').text();
       console.log(firstCellContent); // gives cell 1
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr> 
    <th> column 1<th>
    <th> column 2<th>
    <th> column 3<th>
    <th> column 4<th>
  </tr>
    <tr> 
    <td> cell 1<td>
    <td> cell 2<td>
    <td> cell 3<td>
    <td> cell 4<td>
  </tr>


</table>
```